# Jest cannot resolve module imports in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jestjs, alias

I am trying to include test in a pretty big and established project. I've managed to configure jest and make it work, but I've encontered a problem when importing using aliases.

```
Cannot find module '@app/<dir>/<myFile>.<extension>'
```

My first thought was to change my imports from my test to relative in order to check if the problem were my test. By doing that I only get the same error but now from the imports of the component I mount in the test.

So, I went and looked for a solution to make Jest understand module aliases. I've tried several thing and cannnot make it work, so I hope someone can see what I'm missing and help me to configure it.

Since this is a pretty big project I am trying to avoid updating the Angular version.

Here is all the configuration I have right now:

**package.json**

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "9.1.15",
    "@angular/animations": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/material": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "9.1.13",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "11.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.1.13",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.5.0",
    "@testing-library/angular": "10.3.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "12.7.4",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.20",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.157",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "fishery": "^2.2.2",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.3.2",
    "ngx-translate-testing": "4.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "app/*"
      ],
      "@env/*": [
        "environments/*"
      ]
    },
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop":true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    './jest.setup.ts'
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  verbose: true,
  roots: [ '<rootDir>/src/' ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1",
  },
};
```

I've also tried configuring `moduleNameMapper` with  `"^@app/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1"` and a few more variants.

**jest.setup.ts**

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```